# Selecting up-vote and down-vote totals using a boolean field

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have a table with fields `user_id` and `votes`. The `votes` field is either `1` for an up vote, or `0` for down vote.

What I'd like to do is display the total up votes and total down votes in one query for a specific user.

I was thinking I could maybe use `GROUP BY` somehow to achieve this, but I don't know if I can use it with a `SUM` function somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` would only be necessary if you wanted the vote count for multiple users; with a single user, one need only specify a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(votes=1) AS upvotes, SUM(votes=0) AS downvotes
FROM   my_table
WHERE  user_id = ?
```

As an aside, you might want to consider having downvotes stored as `-1` (instead of `0`) in order that the net vote count can easily be calculated as just `SUM(votes)`.